# Windows 7 IIS7.5 and asp application Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: iis, windows-7, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP aplication and now I installed that on my new PC with Windows7 64bit and IIS 7.5. The problem is that when the app tries to open de dabase, I have this error:
Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

I tried to open the database from this path and it works correctly. The fact is that I have my asp aplicacion on inetpub\wwwroot directory, but the access database is on C:\ProgramData\MyApp\bbdd.mdb  it would be something with permisions? I added a IUSR_XXX user but it is not working too

any help or clue?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In IIS 7.0 and 7.5, the classic version of ASP is not installed by default**. Because of this, you might see HTTP 404 errors when you try to browse to an ASP page on your server, or you might see the source code for your ASP page displayed in your browser window.

Both of these error conditions are created when configuration settings that are used to define the environment for classic ASP are not installed.

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn Windows Features on or off.
3. Expand Internet Information Services, then World Wide Web Services, then Application Development Features.
4. Select ASP, and then click OK.

[Classic ASP Not Installed by Default on IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis-70-and-iis-75/)

Comment: yep! sorry, I have this done and still doesn´t work. ah! I just installed WebMatrix and it is running from there! but not from IIS server O_O

Comment: What kind of error you got after installed the ASP ? If you can explain will help us to help you

Comment: the error says Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found. The resource you are looking for has been renamed or is not available at this time. The erros happens when it tries to open an access database. But now, with webmatrix works perfectly

Comment: Shortly u have to set some more settings to let it work:
Follow this guideline step by step: [Asp, MDB and IIS 7.5](http://digitallibraryworld.com/?p=6)

Comment: Hi Luka, I had windows 7 home basic, so in this, not having the classic ASP to install on the windows features beneath the Internet information services -> application development features, Is any possiblilites to get the classic ASP on windows features