# How to run .asp code on Windows7, 64 bit? Since the ASP folder in Windows Feature is already checked, still giving an error, "HTTP 404 Not Found"?

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-7-x64

IIS is already started but still asp page is not being displayed. Can somebody tell me how to run Classic ASP programs on Windows7 64 bit, I am new to ASP.

Comment: did you install the ASP classic feature? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329647/windows-7-iis7-5-and-asp-application-error-http-404-0-not-found

Comment: No, How should I do that will you please tell me..

Comment: It's clearly explained in the link I provided!

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni Did that linked article fix your issue?

Comment: @kloarubeek,Okay I will see that, and get back to you.

Comment: @Lankymart, No I did'nt see that till now, I am busy with some other task, after completing that I will get back with this one. And thanks for asking.

Comment: I have already activated features still giving error,  
"The webpage cannot be found" .

Comment: Can somebody tell me, please how to run .asp program on windows 7?

Comment: Issue solved I just changed the setting in IIS Manager set Enable Parent Paths to true and Send Errors To Browser to true and it happened. Localhost Home Page of IIS was displayed and my asp scripts are also running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved I just changed the setting in IIS Manager set Enable Parent Paths to true and Send Errors To Browser to true and it happened. Localhost Home Page of IIS was displayed and my asp scripts are also running.